# mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource error?

Tags: php, mysql

Creating a login system for something and am getting:

> Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in .../func/user.func.php on line 21

Here is my code:

```
function user_register($email, $name, $password) {

}

function user_exists($email) {
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'email' ='$email'");

  //this is line 21:
  return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is full of syntax errors, single quotes are used to quote string literals, backticks (or double quotes in standard SQL) are used for identifiers. Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
```

You don't need to quote any of those identifiers so don't bother.

From the [fine manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, **mysql_query()** returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

You probably want to add some error checking after you've fixed your SQL syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your query. If you want to figure out what the error is, output it with [mysql_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your query has syntax errors. You're using single quotes on field and table names. That changes from them being field/table names to being ordinary strings. So your query boils down to `count(some string) from someotherstring where yetanotherstring`.

If your query call had been constructed something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
```

you'd have been informed of the syntax error. As it stands now, your code assumes the query succeeds, which is a very bad thing to do. There's precisely **ONE** way for a query to succeed, and far too many ways for it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no error handling, so if anything goes wrong, it continues on blissfully unaware trying to make soup out of stones. Take a look at the examples in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php), they all check for errors in the query before they try to analyze the result.